# Alfresco CMIS, Bad filenames for download of files

Tags: url, filenames, alfresco, cmis

I have a website that have an integration against an Alfresco installation through CMIS. The problem is that the content-url that I get from Alfresco is ugly. The major problem is that the filename is "content.xxx" (xxx-being the file-extension).

In another project we have solved this by streaming the document through the website and then to the visitor, but for this case (internal web) that doesn't make any sence and only introduce another source for problems. But I can't make the user to accept content.xxx as filename for all files they are going to use so I need a way to fix this.

Is streaming the file through the website my best choise after all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'ugly', and this seems rather subjective. Could you post an example of the complete CMIS URL as well as an example of the type of URL you would prefer to see?

Comment: Are you directly opening CMIS URLs from the browser?

Comment: +Will Abson Ugly becuase the actual filename isn't used in the url. Neither is the structure of the url matching the placement of the file (although much less important)

Comment: +Gagravarr I'm using the url to the content (the actual file) that are giving in the xml that I get in the CMIS-response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you may be using the deprecated CMIS URLs. When I get the content stream for an object named "test.txt" using the appropriate CMIS URLs and the AtomPub binding (/alfresco/cmisatom) I use the following URL:
/alfresco/cmisatom/1b8980cc-1f1b-4ac3-b26f-17aeee0cefc9/content/test.txt?id=workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore%2Fc20d54f9-01b6-4c80-861b-094c2246ab21%3B1.0

If I then connect using the deprecated URL (/alfresco/s/api/cmis) the content stream URL becomes:
/alfresco/s/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/c20d54f9-01b6-4c80-861b-094c2246ab21/content.txt

Can you double-check that you are using the non-deprecated URL and see if this addresses your issue?

Comment: I was wrong, I answered prematurly. Nothing answers on /alfresc/cmisatom/ I get an answer on /alfresco/cmis that seems to list some information. So I'm not sure how to build the url. The installation is an Alfresco 3.4 enterprise, i think.

Comment: The /alfresco/cmisatom URL is available as of 4.0.

Comment: So I guess I have to live with "content.doc" untill the customer decides to upgrade then or stream the content though a special funktion (I don't develop in Alfresco, just a comsumer of the service).